# Eclipse - FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, tomcat

I'm trying to debug a project but immediately I received this error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/eclipse/jdt/launching/internal/javaagent/Premain : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:300)
at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:397)
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
Exception in thread "main"
```

The same project works when i click "Run" but it breaks when I try to debug.

I have a server with the Runtime Environment = Apache Tomcat v7.0 and I use jdk1.7.0_80

What can I do?

Comment: Class version 52 means that you have something compiled with JDK1.8 so it won't run in 1.7

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)